# Why am I receiving protobuff errors when using pip to install packages?

Tags: python, pip, protocol-buffers, python-3.6

I understand that protobuf is a binary serialization format from Google meant to serialize structured data. Why am i receiving protobuff errors like below when for example i am trying to install the aquests package using pip?

Error:

"tensorflow 1.7.0 has requirement protobuf>=3.4.0, but you'll have protobuf 3.1.0.post1 which is incompatible."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [protobuf](https://pypi.org/project/protobuf/) is a Python package that implements said protocol, and `tensorflow` requires later version than you already have. Run `pip install -U tensorflow` instead of `pip install tensorflow` or at least `pip install -U 'protobuf>=3.4.0'`.